# Python time clock without backlight

Tags: python, i2c, hd44780

I'm getting a little desperate, I'm trying to display the current time via a Raspberry pi with an HD44780 and an I2C chip. This works quite well, but now I want that the backlight remains off. The corresponding code snippet that my script sends is interpreted correctly, but every time the time is updated (and the LCD is supposed to write a new text) the backlight flashes briefly. I need this functionality programmatically, since, as soon as the problem is solved, still further functionality is to be added to the Script, in which the backlight is to be switched on again temporarily.

Running Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.2.3
#Date And Time Script

from time import sleep, strftime
from subprocess import *
import lcddriver

lcd = lcddriver.lcd()

def run_cmd(cmd):
    p = Popen(cmd, shell = True, stdout = PIPE)
    output = p.communicate()[0]
    return output

lcd.lcd_clear()

while True:
    lcd.lcd_display_string(strftime('%d.%m.%Y %H:%M'), 1)
    lcd.lcd_device.write_cmd( 0x03 | 1 )
    sleep(1)
```

Imported Script

```
import i2c_lib
from time import *

# LCD Address
ADDRESS = 0x27     #Update Address For LCD Here

# commands
LCD_CLEARDISPLAY = 0x01
LCD_RETURNHOME = 0x02
LCD_ENTRYMODESET = 0x04
LCD_DISPLAYCONTROL = 0x08
LCD_CURSORSHIFT = 0x10
LCD_FUNCTIONSET = 0x20
LCD_SETCGRAMADDR = 0x40
LCD_SETDDRAMADDR = 0x80

# flags for display entry mode
LCD_ENTRYRIGHT = 0x00
LCD_ENTRYLEFT = 0x02
LCD_ENTRYSHIFTINCREMENT = 0x01
LCD_ENTRYSHIFTDECREMENT = 0x00

# flags for display on/off control
LCD_DISPLAYON = 0x04
LCD_DISPLAYOFF = 0x00
LCD_CURSORON = 0x02
LCD_CURSOROFF = 0x00
LCD_BLINKON = 0x01
LCD_BLINKOFF = 0x00

# flags for display/cursor shift
LCD_DISPLAYMOVE = 0x08
LCD_CURSORMOVE = 0x00
LCD_MOVERIGHT = 0x04
LCD_MOVELEFT = 0x00

# flags for function set
LCD_8BITMODE = 0x10
LCD_4BITMODE = 0x00
LCD_2LINE = 0x08
LCD_1LINE = 0x00
LCD_5x10DOTS = 0x04
LCD_5x8DOTS = 0x00

# flags for backlight control
LCD_BACKLIGHT = 0x08
LCD_NOBACKLIGHT = 0x00

En = 0b00000100 # Enable bit
Rw = 0b00000010 # Read/Write bit
Rs = 0b00000001 # Register select bit

class lcd:
   #initializes objects and lcd
   def __init__(self):
      self.lcd_device = i2c_lib.i2c_device(ADDRESS)

      self.lcd_write(0x03)
      self.lcd_write(0x03)
      self.lcd_write(0x03)
      self.lcd_write(0x02)

      self.lcd_write(LCD_FUNCTIONSET | LCD_2LINE | LCD_5x8DOTS | LCD_4BITMODE)
      self.lcd_write(LCD_DISPLAYCONTROL | LCD_DISPLAYON)
      self.lcd_write(LCD_CLEARDISPLAY)
      self.lcd_write(LCD_ENTRYMODESET | LCD_ENTRYLEFT)
      sleep(0.2)

   # clocks EN to latch command
   def lcd_strobe(self, data):
      self.lcd_device.write_cmd(data | En | LCD_BACKLIGHT)
      sleep(.0005)
      self.lcd_device.write_cmd(((data & ~En) | LCD_BACKLIGHT))
      sleep(.0001)

   def lcd_write_four_bits(self, data):
      self.lcd_device.write_cmd(data | LCD_BACKLIGHT)
      self.lcd_strobe(data)

   # write a command to lcd
   def lcd_write(self, cmd, mode=0):
      self.lcd_write_four_bits(mode | (cmd & 0xF0))
      self.lcd_write_four_bits(mode | ((cmd << 4) & 0xF0))

   # put string function
   def lcd_display_string(self, string, line):
      if line == 1:
         self.lcd_write(0x80)
      if line == 2:
         self.lcd_write(0xC0)
      if line == 3:
         self.lcd_write(0x94)
      if line == 4:
         self.lcd_write(0xD4)

      for char in string:
         self.lcd_write(ord(char), Rs)

   # clear lcd and set to home
   def lcd_clear(self):
      self.lcd_write(LCD_CLEARDISPLAY)
      self.lcd_write(LCD_RETURNHOME)
```

Comment: You can permanently disable the backlight using `lcddriver.LCD_BACKLIGHT = 0`

Comment: @quamrana Thanks for your answer. Problem is, that I need to turn it on later as mentioned. The clock should run in a kind of standby mode without lighting and when I later display a message, the lighting should be on again while the message is displayed.

Comment: It sounds like you need to re-write `class lcd` to have separate methods for the backlight.

Answer (score 0):

### You can reimplement this two method:

`def lcd_strobe(self, data):
self.lcd_device.write_cmd(data | En | LCD_NOBACKLIGHT)
sleep(.0005)
self.lcd_device.write_cmd(((data & ~En) | LCD_NOBACKLIGHT))
sleep(.0001)

def lcd_write_four_bits(self, data):
self.lcd_device.write_cmd(data | LCD_NOBACKLIGHT)
self.lcd_strobe(data)`

instead of LCD_BACKLIGHT put LCD_NOBACKLIGHT